# NetBeans could not install some modules

Tags: java, php, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using NetBeans 7.4 DEVELOPMENT VERSION 2, All packages.

First I used NetBeans 7.2, All packages. Then I was notified that I have updates. So I updated it to 7.4 DEVELOPMENT VERSION.

Then again I was notified that I have updates, and I started updating. But by mistake, I clicked a php file while NetBeans was updating, and an error occurred that caused the update to fail. I can't remember the error message.

**Now my problem is that when I start NetBeans, I get the following error message : **

```
Warning - could not install some modules: org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-runtime-compatibility-auth.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.equinox.registry - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.registry state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.core.contenttype - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-contenttype.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.contenttype state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.equinox.app - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-app.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.app state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.core.runtime - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-runtime.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.runtime state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.equinox.security - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-equinox-security.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.equinox.security state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.core.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3 Beta 2\ide\modules\org-eclipse-core-net.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.core.net state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-net.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-xmlrpc.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-repositories-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-tasks-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-bugzilla-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core state remains INSTALLED after start() org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: C:\Users\Arif Rana\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3beta2\modules\org-eclipse-mylyn-wikitext-core.jar: Cannot start org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core state remains INSTALLED after start()
```

[image]

**Now if I click "Disable Modules and Continue", the plugins are disabled.  Then if I try to activate the plugins, I get another error message. The following image is the error message while activating "Developing Netbeans" plugin.**

[image]

I don't want to uninstall NetBeans from my pc as I am very much used to with it, and I have custom settings.

**So I need help on how to repair my installed copy of NetBeans.**

Answer (score 33):

It's very simple :

1 - Try to find this file /home/yourname/.cache/netbeans

2 - And clear all files [image]

Comment: On Windows, the path do clear is anything in the following folder: C:\Users\\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

Comment: I have deleted cache files but still same error occurring. Can anyone help?

Comment: @mujaffars delete data from here too: ```C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\ ```
Now Its working fine in my case.

Answer (score 13):

**1.** Uninstall Net Beans

**2.**  Just Delete everything from:

```
C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\

C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\

I am using 8.1 version.
```

**3.**  After deleting just restart your machine.

**4.**  Re-Install

I did the following steps and it worked :)

Comment: I was able to fix this issue just doing #2 and restarting Netbeans. I'm using version 8. I did not need to reinstall Netbeans.

Comment: @D.B. that grt.. :D

Comment: I am getting this for Netbeans 8.2 when running the installer. Tried the solution and didn't work.

Comment: Netbeans 8.2 on W7, fixed after deleting the Roaming Folder as described here at 2., deleting the Cache folder seems to have to effect

Comment: Steps 1,2 and 4 fixed my issue. No restart was needed in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. If you will get version 7.4 and install it on a clean PC (or remove all netbeans data/config folders) and disable the check for updates, during installation the installation will proceed without errors and netbeans runs. In the case of the first update, the issue comes back.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues for my netbeans 12.2 and 12.3 (I installed netbeans 12.0 12.1 12.2 12.3 and 12.4. All work fine but today 12.2 and 12.3 has the same problem with you. I try to find the solution in the web and i find this youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTHaI_AWhTw
Although it is different issue but the same pattern. So I try to follow his solution.
I find in my file netbeans.conf :
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15"
and change it to
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16"
than i save it. When I run again netbeans it pop up the warning:
Cant find jdk 16 do you want to use Default version?
I click Yes, then the program install all modules and work fine.
When I close the program and run again, the same warning still pop up and I click Yes it work fine. So I open the file netbeans.conf and I change back to
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15".
Save it. When I run netbeans work fine without warning.
I hope that it will work for all of you with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the modules directory (in userdir http://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/DevFaqUserDir.asciidoc), locate the files that appear in that error (like `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth`) and delete or move them in another directory.

Comment: first see [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vlWJiagJaofoe4f0C40uPJOoMjgQ9w3MNDeEoqaVb8o/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vlWJiagJaofoe4f0C40uPJOoMjgQ9w3MNDeEoqaVb8o/edit?usp=sharing) I have move all the highlighted .jar files to another directory but unfortunately the error is still occurring I don't know why ? thanks for the help. If I am doing anything wrong mention me.

Comment: The above link in the answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Apache Netbeans 11.2. As mentioned above deleting Cache worked but I will add I replaced the install folder, I did not have an installer. By unzipping the download again and replacing the install folder, it worked, the zipped download was good but it seems the install folder was corrupted also.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with one version delete the file

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\netbeans_version
```

if have other version in this case me be your ide import setting from other version you should delete all version in the directory

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
```

[image: import setting for other version netbeans]